# Java 1.7 vs C# List/Set/Map syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, java

The following is supposed to be part of Java 1.7:

```
List<String> list = ["item"];
String item = list[0];

Set<String> set = {"item"};

Map<String, Integer> map = {"key" : 1};
int value = map["key"];
```

The same can pretty much be done in C# (and VB.NET) with a slightly difference syntax. In .NET, this is implemented as [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which is a language feature any developer can use to apply onto own classes.

Does anyone know if these feature are **strictly hardcoded** for List, Set, and Map and subclasses or there is a more general language feature behind this?

Comment: I doubt they added indexers to `Java` like the `C#` ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to two distinct features of [Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/) that were *NOT* [accepted for inclusion](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five) in JDK 7.

1. [Support for Collection literals](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html)

   ```
   SomeClass a;
   SomeClass b;
   List<SomeClass> list = [a, b];
   Map<String, SomeClass> map = { "key1": a, "key2": b };
   Set<SomeClass> set = { a, b };
   ```

   It should be noted that these literals only allow for the creation of *unmodifiable* (read-only in .NET) collections. As far as I know, such literals do not exist in C# (except for arrays, but such literals have also existed in Java for a long time). It also does not have anything to do with indexed properties.
2. [Indexing access syntax for Lists and Maps](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001108.html)

   ```
   List<SomeClass> l = new ArrayList<>();
   SomeClass first = new SomeClass();
   l[0] = first; // instead of l.set(0, first);
   SomeClass retrieved = l[0] // instead of l.get(0);
   // Similar thing for maps.
   ```

   That is the feature which is implemented in C# as indexed properties, and it only applies to the `List` and `Map` interfaces (remember that, contrary to the .NET Class Library, the Java interfaces are not usually prefixed with an `I`) - it is nothing more than a transformation, by the compiler, into calls to these methods.

In both cases, there is no general language feature, just a bit of syntactic sugar:

- For the first feature, the compiler will transform the literal into a call to a few methods to create a unmodifiable `List`, `Set` or `Map`. (I seem to remember that the concrete classes that are returned are not even publicly visible.)
- For the second feature, the compiler will just transform the expression into calls to the relevant methods, as long as the class implements the `List` or `Map` interface.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of those features made it into JDK7.  The Java language changes that made the cut are listed [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/#f618) as:

> JSR 334: Small language enhancements (Project Coin).  A set of small language changes intended to simplify common, day-to-day programming tasks: Strings in switch statements, try-with-resources statements, improved type inference for generic instance creation ("diamond"), simplified varargs method invocation, better integral literals, and improved exception handling (multi-catch)

The remaining "Project Coin" features and other language changes were punted to JDK8:

> JSR 294: Language and VM support for modular programming. Enhancements to the Java language and virtual-machine specifications to support modular programming, at both compile time and run time
>
> JSR 308: Annotations on Java types. An extension to the Java annotation syntax to permit annotations on any occurrence of a type
>
> JSR TBD: Language support for collections. Literal expressions for immutable lists, sets,
>
> JSR TBD: Project Lambda. Lambda expressions (informally, "closures") and defender methods for the Java programming language

Answer (score 0):

They want add some features which other languages（static/dynamic）  already have into Java.The initialization way for the map is the same as some dynamic languages.